# NO CARRIER with Huawei ME906s

Tags: linux, debian, modem, wwan

With my Huawei ME906s on Linux (tested with debian sid, debian experimental, Fedora 24 and Ubuntu 16.04, but the result's the same under Windows 10), I get either `ERROR` or `NO CARRIER` messages (depending on which device I'm using). In contrast to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/527543/randomly-getting-no-carrier-from-huawei-3g-modem-under-linux), the behavior is consistent and also occurs when I run wvdial long after boot. I have removed the SIM PIN and verified that the mobile network works with an Android smartphone.

Using Linux 4.7.0-rc4, I see 5 devices I can associate to the card:

- `/dev/ttyUSB0` - Speaks AT, output shown below
- `/dev/ttyUSB1` - No output (for GPS?)
- `/dev/ttyUSB2` - Speaks AT, but answers ERROR instead of NO CARRIER to dial
- `/dev/ttyUSB3` - Same behavior as /dev/ttyUSB0
- `/dev/ttyUSB4` - No output (for GPS?)

Here's the output I get with a [specially crafted wvdial.conf](https://gist.github.com/phihag/7c045976849bccbc2ebf5fcd3d4e2e4c):

```
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: AT+CFUN=1
AT+CFUN=1
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0
OK
--> Sending: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet.t-mobile"
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet.t-mobile"
OK
--> Sending: ATI
ATI
Manufacturer: Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
Model: ME906s-158
Revision: 11.617.00.00.00
IMEI: 8<snip by @phihag>0
+GCAP: +CGSM,+DS,+ES
OK
--> Sending: AT+CPIN?
AT+CPIN?
+CPIN: READY
OK
--> Sending: AT+CFUN?
AT+CFUN?
+CFUN: 1
OK
--> Sending: AT+CSQ
AT+CSQ
+CSQ: 99,99
OK
--> Sending: AT+CREG?
AT+CREG?
+CREG: 0,2
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATD*99#
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATD*99#
NO CARRIER
--> No Carrier!  Trying again.
```

The last 5 lines are then repeated 10+ times.

Other tools like sakis3g and ModemManager/NetworkManager hang as well while trying to connect.

I am also seeing a network link associated with the modem, but that's not reachable either:

```
$ ip link
...
6: enp0s20f0u5c2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:1e:10:1f:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I believe `rfkill` not to be active:

```
$ rfkill list
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: tpacpi_wwan_sw: Wireless WAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
10: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

(talking to `/dev/ttyUSB0`)

```
AT^RFSWITCH?
^RFSWITCH: 1,1

OK
```

[As suggested](https://superuser.com/a/1085949/62132), I tried using `AT^NDISDUP` instead, to no avail (although at the next `ATZ` I see additional lines):

```
$ minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0
ATZ
OK
^PDPSTATUS: 2
^NDISSTAT: 0,0,,"IPV4"
AT^NDISDUP=1,1,"internet.t-mobile"
OK

AT^DHCP?
ERROR
```

However, `ip link` still shows NO-CARRIER, and `dhclient -v enp0s20f0u5c2` times out as well. With `ethtool` I see:

```
$ ethtool -i enp0s20f0u5c2
driver: cdc_ether
version: 22-Aug-2005
firmware-version: CDC Ethernet Device
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: usb-0000:00:14.0-5
supports-statistics: no
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: no
supports-priv-flags: no
```

dmesg looks good to me:

```
[   11.674523] cdc_ether 1-5:2.0 usb0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-5, CDC Ethernet Device, 02:1e:10:1f:00:00
[   11.674630] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[   11.675451] option 1-5:2.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   11.675746] usb 1-5: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[   11.675767] option 1-5:2.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   11.676499] usb 1-5: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[   11.676528] option 1-5:2.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   11.676569] usb 1-5: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[   11.676586] option 1-5:2.5: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   11.676620] usb 1-5: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
[   11.676637] option 1-5:2.6: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   11.676672] usb 1-5: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB4
```

Similarily, the [`lsusb` output](https://gist.github.com/phihag/7c045976849bccbc2ebf5fcd3d4e2e4c#file-lsusb-output) looks fairly normal.

How do I get my Huawei ME906s to connect?

Comment: I've updated the question: Yes, I've tried sakis3g and ModemManager&NetworkManager, without success. I believe both are much more high-level than my approach.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the AT^RFSWITCH? status? It should return AT^RFSWITCH: 1,1. If there are any zeroes, then the modem is in rfkill "airplane" mode.

The huawei modem has two rfswitch (also known as rflock or rfkill) settings: one hardware and one software.  The Software rf-kill can be disabled by issuing AT^RFSWITCH=1.

The hardware setting must be disabled from your mainboard/platform, as it actually pulls low a pin on the M.2/mPCIe connector. On laptops this is often controlled by a ACPI function key.  On my X260, this is exposed on Linux as /sys/class/rfkill/rfkill3/state

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, the output is `^RFSWITCH: 1,1` (without the `AT`, but I guess that's correct) on my modem. Also, `rfkill` shows `no` everywhere, and `cat /sys/class/rfkill/*/state` outputs a bunch of `1`s.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try a more recent connection method:

```
AT^NDISDUP=1,1,"internet.t-mobile"
```

Then use a DHCP client on your `enp0s20f0u5c2` interface that you see.

If you are connected, then `AT^DHCP?` should also yield an answer with your IP in hexadecimal notation.

Comment: This got two upvotes, I would be interested if this method works as intended.

Comment: I apologize for the delay. It took some time for me to test the SIM card in a phone, find out that the contract expired, and acquire a new one. I have updated the question with the result of using NDISDUP instead - unfortunately, I see no significant difference.

Comment: No problem, I would have just used NDISDUP and no command after that, it seems that you used ATD*99# after entering NDISDUP.

Comment: I've removed the `ATD` (I'm not connecting manually using minicom instead of wvdial), but I still see the same behavior - the `enp0s20f0u5c2` device is marked as NO-CARRIER and I am unable to connect. Surprisingly, `AT^DHCP?` is answered with `ERROR`. Is that ever supposed to happen?

Comment: I am not sure on the latter.
Which driver is your interface using? `ethtool -i enp0s20f0u5c2` it might be `cdc_mbim` and if yes `mbimcli` might a next approach.
DHCP is not mandatory if I remember correctly for passing IPs to the interface, especially with MBIM. It was however used in previous ethernet stuff, like NCM. My modem is a E3372 which uses NCM and I assumed similarities between the models.

Comment: I've added that output as well to the question, at the very end. `cdc_ether` seems to be the one associated to WWAN.

Comment: Thanks, this was unexpected by me however. Which Kernel version are you using?

Comment: I've tried with various recent kernels, currently on 4.6.0-1, which I believe to be fairly recent.

Comment: Are you using the device with a Laptop? I would assume so, but the `ip link` status of `DOWN` wonders me. Might there be a radio hard switch not working correctly? 
Maybe you can parse `dmesg` to find out what the modem is doing while bootup, or a `lsusb` output.
The reason for the kernel was this commit: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/net/usb?id=c5b5343cfbc9f46af65033fa4f407d7b7d98371d

Comment: Yes, this is on a Lenovo T460p. I have reproduced the behavior with the very recent 4.7.0-rc4 kernel which includes this bugfix. The [lsusb output](https://gist.github.com/phihag/7c045976849bccbc2ebf5fcd3d4e2e4c#file-lsusb-output) and dmesg (added at the bottom of the question) both look normal to me. Maybe this is a simple hardware error, like antenna not connected?

Comment: Might be, but I would assume even with no antennas being connected that still sometimes, a very weak signal would be received, here it seems that the `ERROR` appears instantly.
I am out of ideas to be honest.
You might try reaching to the ModemManager/libqmi/libmbim developers, Bjorn is usually very friendly and helpful, I think [this](https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/modemmanager-devel) mailing list would be a place to start, and link this thread if you write an email to it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with my ME906s-158 modem. Tried to use it via MBIM - no luck.
Modem had an outdated firmware - so I updated it to latest one got it from  [techship.com](https://techship.com/products/huawei-me906s-158-m2-eu/). After update ME906s worked as expected in cdc_ether mode. Before enabling connection on modem network interface looked as:

```
26: enp0s29u1u2u5c2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
     link/ether 02:1e:10:1f:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I need to enable connection by AT command `AT^NDISDUP=1,1`. And interface got IP via DHCP:

```
26: enp0s29u1u2u5c2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
     link/ether 02:1e:10:1f:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
     inet 10.173.107.197/30 brd 10.173.107.199 scope global dynamic enp0s29u1u2u5c2
       valid_lft 518398sec preferred_lft 518398sec
    inet6 fe80::ef85:b8f8:761e:b922/64 scope link 
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```