# Cannot dial with USB modem

Tags: usb-modem

I have a Huawei USB stick (E3372h-320) running under Linux. I configured usb_modeswitch so it's switched into the modem mode (or "stick mode") rather than the "hilink" mode.
I correctly get three `/dev/ttyUSB*` devices, and I'm playing around with AT commands.

The modem correctly registers in the network, `AT+COPS?` shows it's registered. I am definitely able to send and receive SMS messages without problems (using the `AT+CMGF=1` + `AT+CMGS=<number>` commands. `AT+CSQ` gives good signal strength.

The SIM card works perfectly in a mobile phone.

So far so good. However, now I'm trying to get the modem to dial some number, and that's where things are not working.
Any syntax for the `ATD<number>` command I tried (with/without quotes around the number, with/without semicolon at the end, with/without country code, with `T`, with `P`) resulted in an immediate `NO CARRIER` response from the modem.

Now I could certainly be missing something, but the main thing I'd like to understand now is: Is `ATD` supposed to be working in my scenario? Does it depend on the modem? On the operator? On the SIM? On something else? How do I check? Of course if it cannot work or is not supposed to be working, it's pointless for me to waste more time trying.

Comment: If I were you, I would move this to StackOverflow and post your code too.  It is hard to judge without seeing what you are actually doing in the code.  This site has a lot of mega-geeks (good ones too) but many/most don't read code or know how to interpret the ***hayes command set***.

Comment: I'll take the advice, however there's really no code involved here, I'm typing everything into minicom.

Comment: @JohnSmith you're in the right place.  Does any of this help: https://superuser.com/questions/1079052/no-carrier-with-huawei-me906s

Comment: Looks to me that the OP in that thread is trying to dial `*99#` (which AFAIK is not a regular number) to establish an IP link. Here I'm trying to dial a real phone number. Anyway, I tested the suggestions there: `AT^RFSWITCH?` results in `ERROR` for me.

Comment: I'm not sure about whether I need a PDP context (and hence the `AT^NDISDUP` and/or `AT+CGDCONT` commands) to dial regular numbers, would be grateful for any clarification.